# Criar grid interativa com CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Queria criar um *grid* interativa onde quando a pessoa clicasse na imagem esta mesma aparecesse grande ao lado, estilo site de compras.

```
<div id='gridImagens>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <img src"miniatura.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
               <img src"miniatura.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
               <img src"miniatura.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src='imgs/imgGrande.jpg' />
    </div>    
</div>
```

Queiria que ao clicar em uma das imagens miniaturas essa imagen aparecesse no lugar da imgGrande

Comment: Ok, qual é seu nível de conhecimento em HTML, JavaScript e CSS? Tem como descrever o que já tentou fazer? Você pode [edit] a pergunta e adicionar a estrutura do HTML, pelo menos. Se possuir JS e CSS, busque fazer um [mcve] e pode utilizar o *snippet* para executá-lo (botão `</>` do editor da pergunta). Para mais informações, leia o guia de [ask] e faça o [tour] para entender como a comunidade funciona.

Comment: Meu nivel de conhecimento e basico, estou comecando nesta area ainda nao fiz nada em javaScript e css para esta pergunta, somente a estrutura em html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe uma maneira de fazer isso sem precisar de *JavaScript*.

Nesse exemplo abaixo substitua as imagens *small* pela miniatura e *large* pela imagem grande.

> A `div` das imagens grandes está ajustada para 500x375
>   pixels, portanto se for utilizar imagens com tamanhos diferentes
>   deverá ajustar o CSS das imagens ou mudar o tamanho da
>   `div`.

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
  <ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="#pic1"><img alt="" src="small_nature1.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#pic2"><img alt="" src="small_nature2.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#pic3"><img alt="" src="small_nature3.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#pic4"><img alt="" src="small_nature4.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#pic5"><img alt="" src="small_nature5.jpg" /></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="full-picture">
    <div><a name="pic1"></a><img alt="" src="large_nature1.jpg" /></div>
    <div><a name="pic2"></a><img alt="" src="large_nature2.jpg" /></div>
    <div><a name="pic3"></a><img alt="" src="large_nature3.jpg" /></div>
    <div><a name="pic4"></a><img alt="" src="large_nature4.jpg" /></div>
    <div><a name="pic5"></a><img alt="" src="large_nature5.jpg" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#gallery {
  width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border: 2px solid #003C72;
}

#navigation {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

#navigation li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

#navigation li a img {
  display: block;
  border: none;
}

#navigation li a {
  display: block;
}

#full-picture {
  width: 500px;
  height: 375px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}
```

**[Fonte](https://basicuse.net/articles/pl/textile/html_css/how_to_create_a_simple_css_gallery_without_using_javascript)**

**[Demonstração](https://basicuse.net/articles/pl/textile/html_css/how_to_create_a_simple_css_gallery_without_using_javascript/example)**

Comment: Muito Obrigado era exatamente isso que eu queria.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que usar um Modal seria interessante, posso te recomendar o site da w3school (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp) ele me ajudou bastante para ter uma noção no inicio.

Comment: Gostei desse exemplo. obrigado.